# How do I make a function that adds once and subtract once for every number in the list?

Tags: python, list

This is my code, but I figured out that it only works if the numbers are 'even and odd in that order' so, How do I create a function that adds and then subtracts for every number in the list, so like if my list is 1,3,4,5 then the output is 1+3-4+5 or if my list is 4,6,7,4,5,3 then the output would be 4+6-7+4-5+3... please help

```py
def alt_sum(lst):
    total = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(lst):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            total += value
        else:
            total -= value
    return total

print(alt_sum([3, 4, 5, 8]))
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't work with "only even and odd" it already works with alternate numbers. you are checking the index value with %2, not the actual value.

Comment: I don't believe your explanation is clear. If you  want to add then then subtract then for `[1,3,4,5]` you would do `1-3+4-5`. Maybe this is what's tripping you up. Define what you want, use unit tests to aid you, and step through debugging if you are still having issues.

Comment: You add the first two numbers, it's only alternating excluding the first index

Comment: No, OP wanted to do 1+3-4+5 `How do I create a function that adds and then subtracts for every number in the list, so like if my list is 1,3,4,5 then the output is 1+3-4+5 `, but they believe that this is only happening with the even and odd numbers. but its not that. its happening with even and odd indexes.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I am pretty sure they are aware of that since they are clearly checking the index and using `enumerate` and they have correctly labeled which is value and which is index, maybe they mixed it up a little or something but it more of seems they want to alternate between indexes, tho I agree it is pretty confusing

Comment: @Matiiss, dont think that is true, based on their first sentence. `This is my code, but I figured out that it only works if the numbers are 'even and odd in that order'`

Comment: @AkshaySehgal that is the confusing part: _'even and odd in that order'_ makes me think that _in that order_ is meant as index in the list

Comment: For me I read it as "even and odd, in that order" meaning they believe that the sum/subtraction is only happening if the number is even or odd respectively. BUT its actually working as they intended since its working on the indexes due ot enumerate.

Comment: either way too much confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your explanation and sample intput/output differs.
your code is right by your explanation if you meant `even and odd in that order` as index, but is wrong based on sample input/output. Heres what should be based on sample input/output:

```
def alt_sum(lst):
    total = lst[0]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            total -= lst[i]
        else:
            total += lst[i]
    return total

print(alt_sum([3, 4, 5, 8]))
```

same thing, I'd prefer the above one.

```
def alt_sum(lst):
    return lst[0]+sum([lst[i] for i in range(1,len(lst),2)])-sum([lst[i] for i in range(2,len(lst),2)])
```

Comment: changed `for i in range(1,lst):` to `for i in range(1,len(lst)):`

Comment: Hey! your answer is great but I was just wondering is there an easier way to do this?? It can be longer if it must be but, is there any like easier method to do this.

Comment: this itself is good, it's time complexity is O(n). I'm not sure if this is the easier way but here, it does the same thing  `return lst[0]+sum([lst[i] for i in range(1,len(lst),2)])-sum([lst[i] for i in range(2,len(lst),2)])`

Comment: Can you put this in your code?? I dont know whereto put it LOL

Comment: @DaveShah updated

Answer (score 1):

If the index is greater than 0 and an even number, take the negative value, and then add.

```
def alt_sum(lst):
    alt_lst = [-v if (i % 2 == 0 and i > 0) else v for i, v in enumerate(lst)]
    # print(alt_lst)
    return sum(alt_lst)


print(alt_sum([3, 4, 5, 8]))
```

Comment: Why check the index. What if the first number is odd. Also, I guess you need to interchange `-v` and `v` because op said add negative of the  number if it is odd

Comment: hey, thank u very much for the comment, but I'm very new to this so, can you please explain in detail what u just did. Ur code definitely works but like, I wanna get an in-depth explanation so I can grasp the concept for future purposes , thank you